# Electron-forge & osx sign app result in "Binary is improperly signed."

Tags: macos, electron, electron-forge

I developed an electron app using the following "features":

- Base : [Electron-Forge](https://www.electronforge.io/) : start, make & publish
- Electron [`open-url`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-url-macos) feature [Schemes: xx-note]
- [`node-keytar`](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar) : get & set pwd
- [Frameless App](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window) : transparent windows
- [Auto-Update](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater) with [Nucleus](https://github.com/atlassian/nucleus) : Working on W10
- [Start on login](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetloginitemsettingssettings-macos-windows)

I have no problem to run the application, and build it if I don't sign it, but to make the auto-update work, I absolutely need to sign it. (and it's better for my customers).

Unfortunately, when I sign it and try to run it on Big Sur I get the following message:

From finder :

> **You do not have permission to open the application “XX”**
>
> Contact your computer or network administrator for assistance.

From terminal :

```
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason,
error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10826 "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr: User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)" 
UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2539, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f98fe4166d0 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f98fe418060 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed with error: 153}}}}}
```

And, in both case I have this message in the `Console`/`system.log` :

```
May  3 11:00:32 XX com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (application.ai.XX.note-taking.39302547.39303101[25454]): removing service since it exited with consistent failure - OS_REASON_CODESIGNING | When validating /Users/XX/Documents/XX/mr/XX-desktop/out/XX-darwin-x64/XX.app/Contents/MacOS/XX_Taking-Note:
      Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed.
    Unsatisfied Entitlements: 
May  3 11:00:32 XX com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (application.ai.XX.note-taking.39302547.39303101[25454]): Binary is improperly signed.
```

#### Catalina :

My colleague launched it from Catalina and got this error message

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread:        0
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1
```

### How is my app signed ?

Using [`electron-osx-sign`][8] & [`electron-notarize`][8] with forge config :

```
packagerConfig:  {
    appBundleId: 'ai.XX.note-taking',
    executableName: BUILD_NAME, //XX
    name: APP_NAME, //XX
    icon: iconPath,
    overwrite: true,
    asar: true,

    extendInfo: './info.extends.plist',

    protocols: {
      name: 'XX-note',
      schemes: ['XX-note'],
    },

    osxSign: {
      identity: OSX_CREDENTIALS.SIGN_ID, // Developer ID Application: TeamName (MYTEAMID)
      'hardened-runtime': true,
      entitlements: 'entitlements.plist',
      'entitlements-inherit': 'entitlements.plist',
      'entitlements-loginhelper': 'login.entitlements.plist',
      'signature-flags': 'library',
      // https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize/issues/54
      'gatekeeper-assess': false,
      verbose: true,
    },
    osxNotarize: {
      // appBundleId: 'ai.XX.note-taking', // (TESTED WITH & WITHOUT)
      appleId: OSX_CREDENTIALS.ID, // me@XX.ai"
      appleIdPassword: OSX_CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD, // app password
      // ascProvider: 'MYTEAMID', // (TESTED WITH & WITHOUT)
    },
```

### codesign --verify --verbose XX.app

```
out/XX-darwin-x64/XX.app: valid on disk
out/XX-darwin-x64/XX.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

### My `.plist`

#### login.entitlements.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

#### info.extends.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>XX-note</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <true />
    <key>ElectronTeamID</key>
    <string>MYTEAMID</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

#### entitlements.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I really hope you can help me, I really tried to give you as much as possible, and it's already been more than three days that I'm looking everywhere without solving my problem.

#### Already tried

- developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666611?page=5
- github.com/ElmarJ/Waterlooplein3D/issues/86
- bestofreactjs.com/repo/infinitered-reactotron-react-development-tools
- stackoverflow.com/questions/64842819/cant-run-app-because-of-permission-in-big-sur
- github.com/upx/upx/issues/424
- github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Mac/issues/204
- github.com/Hardocs/desktop-app/issues/56
- discussions.apple.com/thread/526166
- ... AND MORE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this issue using this tutorial : https://kilianvalkhof.com/2019/electron/notarizing-your-electron-application/

And this issue https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3940

My final config is :

```
    osxSign: {
      identity: 'Developer ID Application: MyTeam (TEAMID)',
      'hardened-runtime': true,
      entitlements: 'mac/entitlements.plist',
      'entitlements-inherit': 'mac/entitlements.plist',
      'signature-flags': 'library',
      // https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize/issues/54
      'gatekeeper-assess': false,
      verbose: true,
    },

    osxNotarize: {
      appleId: 'myemail',
      appleIdPassword: 'mypassword',
    },
```

And `mac/entitlements.plist` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```