# Can we sign a mac os app using electron builder with digicert?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, digicert

I have an electron app and i have used electron builder with digicert. I'm able to make it work for windows. Now i'm trying to sign for mac OS using a mac computer. Can we use Digi cert to sign the app?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sign a Mac application, (electron, or any other application) you should generate a certficate comming from apple with [an apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/) (100$/year).

If your are using `electron-forge` they explained in their [documentation](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/code-signing/code-signing-macos) how to do it.

Electron forge uses the tools, which you can use without :

- [electron-osx-sign](https://github.com/electron/osx-sign)
- [electron-notarize](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize)

Like you, I struggled a lot at the beginning, and I give answers to my own question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68176513/15821631

Conclusion : No you can't use your Digicert certificate (windows only), but you will have to get an Apple developper account and a generate a special certificate. Tools exist to sign an app without taking too much trouble. They are well made and well documented. The question has been asked a lot already on Stackoverflow.